# Back button like in file browser

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a document management system for my project. I just want to know if there is a possible way to achieve a back button like in the photo below. 
[see the photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzZe.png)

Here is my code for the document management system:

**index.php**

```
  <main class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="breadcrumb">
          <div class="item"><a href="index.php"> Document</a></div>
      </div>

      <div class="load-data">
        <?php
          require_once 'config.php';
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent='0' ORDER BY sort ASC";

          $folders = $db->prepare($sql);
          $folders->execute();
          $folder = $folders->fetchAll();

          if ($folder) {
              echo "<table>";
                  echo "<thead>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Label</td>
                              <td>Sort</td>
                              <td>Id</td>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>";
                  foreach ($folder as $folderr) {
                  echo    "<tr class='folder-item'>";
                        if($folder['link'] == 'folder'){
                          echo" <td><i class'fa fa-folder'><a href='#' onclick='get_data(".$folderr['id'].")'>".$folderr['label']."</a></td>";
                        }else{
                          echo" <td><i class='fa fa-file'></i><a href='#' onclick='get_data(".$folderr['id'].")'>".$folderr['label']."</a></td>";
                        }
                        echo"      <td>".$folderr['sort']."</td>
                              <td>".$folderr['id']."</td>
                          </tr>";
                  }
              echo "</table>";
          } else {
            echo 'No folder/files found.';
          }

        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

here's the **script**

```
    <script>
        function get_data(id){
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'file.php',
                data : 'folder=' + id,
                success : function(response){
                    $('.load-data').html(response);
                }
            });
        }

        $('.folder-item a').on('click', function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

            $this.parents('td').each(function(n, td) {
                var $a = $(td).children('a').clone();
                $bc.append(' > ', $a);
            });
              $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="index.php">Document</a>') );
              return false;
          }); 
    </script>
```

here's the **file.php**

```
     <?php 
        require_once 'config.php';

        if(isset($_GET['folder'])){
            $id = $_GET['folder'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent='$id' ORDER BY sort ASC";

            $folders = $db->prepare($sql);
            $folders->execute();
            $folder = $folders->fetchAll();

            if ($folder) {
                echo "<table>";
                    echo "<thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Label</td>
                                <td>Sort</td>
                                <td>Id</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>";
                    foreach ($folder as $folderr) {
                        echo    "<tr>";
                        if($folder['link'] == 'folder'){
                          echo" <td><i class'fa fa-folder'><a href='#' onclick='get_data(".$folderr['id'].")'>".$folderr['label']."</a></td>";
                        }else{
                          echo" <td><i class='fa fa-file'></i><a href='#' onclick='get_data(".$folderr['id'].")'>".$folderr['label']."</a></td>";
                        }
                        echo"      <td>".$folderr['sort']."</td>
                              <td>".$folderr['id']."</td>
                          </tr>";
                    }
                echo "</table>";
            } else {

                echo 'No folder/files found.';

            }
        } 

        ?>
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, when you're on the root folder of course there's no back, when you go inside the directory then just add the `..` before the loop and set it as the parent

Comment: @Kevin that's what I wanted to do sir. do you have sample code for that ?

Comment: create a function that check/query if the current directory is a child of a directory..if it is a child...add ".." or a link to its parent

Comment: its a simple if statement (or ternary if you want), if the parent isn't 0 echo it, just add that before the loop, else you're currently in root directory

Comment: sir @Kevin I got the idea but when I'm executing the code I got the ".." but when I click that it returns me to the parent directory.

Comment: @ckien you get the parent directory `..` relative to your current directory. you're already using `$_GET` variable as your basis

Comment: ok, sir got it. thank you for helping me.! :D. Sorry, I'm currently poor at programming I gonna read more about this.